# Multiple testing with one-factor analysis of variance

Tags: anova, multiple-comparisons, false-discovery-rate

I have groups A (N=60), B (N=30), and C (N=30), and 100 variables. Using one-factor analysis of variance (F-test), I would like test whether the three samples differ for each variable. So, if I first run the one-factor ANOVA for each variable, and then correct for false positives using e.g. false discovery rate, everything should be OK? Is there some other approaches I should consider?